# MySQL + Grafana: slow queries on time series data

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, time-series, amazon-rds, grafana

I'm new to Grafana and MySQL, .

I have an IoT device sending data every 1 second to an Amazon RDS Aurora database running with MySQL (db.t3.small). With Grafana, I added the RDS Datasource and created a Dashboard to visualize a sensor value on a chart (5 minutes of data displayed, so 300 values).

I noticed that for the first hours, the queries run fast and the dashboard refreshes in less of a second.

However, after 24 hours of data sent to the database, it takes more than 20 seconds to refresh the dashboard. I tried with a Unix timestamp type stored as an integer and with the TIMESTAMP type of MySQL, but I got the same problem. Here is my query:

```
SELECT
  ts_timestampFormat AS "time",
  LAeq
FROM testsGrafanaTable
WHERE
  $__timeFilter(ts_timestampFormat ) AND
  station_id = 'station-1'
ORDER BY ts_timestampFormat
```

- **Could you help me to understand why this is happening?  Is this related to the query? Or to the database performance?**
- **How I can get a faster query?**

I also tried to use a time range in the WHERE statement, `ts_timestampFormat >= $__timeFrom() AND ts_timestampFormat <= $__timeTo() AND`, but I got the same issue.

Thanks!